# Can I have an alias of function inside the same library in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

Say I have the definition of a function:

```
def rename(src, dst) do
   <do rename>
end
```

inside of my Elixir library, can I then create within the same library:

```
alias rename, as: mv
```

so that when users can use both the rename and mv functions in my library ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The simplest approach I can think of is via [defdelegate](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#defdelegate/2)

```
iex(1)> defmodule Foo do
...(1)>   def foo, do: :foo
...(1)>
...(1)>   defdelegate bar, to: __MODULE__, as: :foo
...(1)> end

iex(2)> Foo.foo
:foo
iex(3)> Foo.bar
:foo
```

Note that this defines another function `bar/0` which invokes `foo/0`.

Answer (score 7):

### If your method accepts arguments:

You would also need to specify the arguments in `defdelegate`:

```
defmodule MyModule do
  def awesome_func(term, opts \\ []) do
    # Do Something
  end

  defdelegate badass_func(term, opts \\ []), to: __MODULE__, as: :awesome_func
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer as of Elixir 1.11 is no, you can't have aliases for functions.

The `defdelegate` does not create an alias, but instead, it creates another function that calls the function for which you wanted an alias.